# Problem on set of zeros

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Is it true that for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ then $V(\mathfrak{p}) \neq \emptyset$?

I know that there are prime ideals with $V(\mathfrak{p}) \neq \emptyset$, but I don't know if this is true for all cases.

Comment: Could you clarify a couple things? (1) Are we in a commutative ring? (2) What is the notation $V(p)$?

Comment: I am working in a polynomial ring $K[X1,...,Xn]$ with coefficients in a field $K$ and $V(p)$ is te set of zeros of ideal $p$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, by Nullstellensatz (for applaying Nullst. you need your base field to be algebraically closed) A prime ideal $p$ is in particular a proper ideal (i.e. strictly contained) in the polynomial ring, and the vanishing set $V(I)$ of an ideal $I$ is empty if and only if the ideal $I$ is the whole ring.

EDIT: prime $\rightarrow$ proper $\rightarrow$ "contained in a maximal ideal, say $\mathfrak{m}$". Maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is of the form
$$\mathfrak{m}=(X_1-a_1,\ldots,X_n-a_n)=V(a)$$
for some point $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of the affine space. But $P\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$ implies $V(\mathfrak{m})\subseteq V(P)$ and $V(\mathfrak{m})$ is non-empty, because $a\in V(\mathfrak{m})$.

Comment: So "no" if the field is not algebraically closed ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes of course, e.g. the field of real numbers and the ideal $P$ generated by $x^2+1$

Comment: Depending on your definitions, though; by some definitions, in the line over the real numbers, the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ does have a root (of 'degree' 2): the complex conjugate pair $\pm i$.

Comment: I have a doubt, what is the meaning of "EDIT", not the word if not the explication. You explain the case that I is the whole ring?

Comment: @rgl4 edit is a sketch of the proof that every proper ideal has a non trivial vanishing set